# Why isn't my wrapped component rendering?

Tags: reactjs, components

App.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import Wrapper from "./Components/Wrapper";
import Header from "./Components/Header";
import "./App.css"
function App(){
   return( 
      <>
         <Wrapper>
            <Header></Header>
         </Wrapper>
      </>
   );
}
export default App;
```

Header.jsx

```
import React from "react";

function Header() {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>This is the header</h1>
    </>
  );
}

export default Header;
```

Wrapper.jsx

```
import React from "react";
function Wrapper(){
    return(
        <>            
            <h1>This is A WRAPPER!</h1>
        </>
    )

}
export default Wrapper;
```

I'm a beginner in React, trying to learn the basic. Why the content of the **Header** component is not rendered in this case? I can only see the content in **Wrapper**

Comment: The "Wrapper" component need to take the so called "children" property and render it - you can check https://react.dev/reference/react/Children to get a better understanding of this.

Answer (score 0):

When a component wraps another component it's passed to it in a special prop called [children](https://react.dev/learn/passing-props-to-a-component#passing-jsx-as-children)
to fix your problem simply make use of this prop like so

```js
function Wrapper(props){
    return(
        <>            
            <h1>This is A WRAPPER!</h1>
            {/*any jsx this components wraps will be passed here */}
            {props.children}
        </>
    )

}
```